# Dismissing multiple view controllers at once with strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is a common problem and for everybody who still doesn't know the correct way how to deal with that, here is the scenario.

Modally presented view controllers A -> B -> C

Now you want to dismiss C with B at one smooth animation landing to view controller A. So apple documentation says that you only need to perform:

```
[A dismissViewConttollerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

And C with B should be nicely gone. This is really often needed scenario and I'm really said and disappointed that the common use case is not working properly. `Why the top view controller C disappears in a moment and B view controller appears with dismissing animation instead of C to be visible for the whole animation process?` I would really except to see only C view controller's dismission.

[image]

Comment: show the code for your demo

Comment: Its controller B that should be dismissed instead of A, as you want to land on A. Ideally, it should be [B dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: When you perform [B dismissViewControllerAnimate:YES completion:nil] it will land on B not A. That's what apple doc says and also tested...

Comment: @Wain There is nth to show... It's really simple use case with no more that 1 line of code. All segues are done via IB only dismiss is performed programatically...

Comment: I guess what you could do is to clear the view controller stack completely (without animation) and then make a fresh (animated) load of view controller A from app delegate. And to make a smooth transition you should probably take a screenshot of C, so that you can make a smooth animated transition while presenting A. It's quiet complicated for my experience level so didn't test it and I don't know if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to use in this case is [Unwind Segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013591). You can directly move switch to any view controller in the heirarchy.

Comment: Yop, this is nice workaround and maybe working, but not usable for many of us struggling with programatically created view controllers hierarchy...

Answer (score 0):

The dismissal of B can't be done in parallel with dismissal of C. This happens sometimes in iOS when the two animations are related somehow - I don't know the exact details.

If you put a breakpoint in C's dismissal completion block, you'll probably see the `finished` parameter being `false`, indicating C's animation has been interrupted.

I think the correct solution is to **dismiss B only**. C will be gone automatically since it was presented by B.

Comment: You're right and that's what I do for now. The dismission in my code example is called only once on A controller and regarding the apple doc C should be gone also with B which is true but the problem is in animation captured in attached gif. You can see that C disappears somehow...

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I think if you are presenting controllers inside controllers then maybe you should use `UINavigationController` rather than presentations. You can modify `UINavigationController`'s transition delegate to make slide-up animation. Maybe not the best solution, but I kind of ran out of ideas :)